# Is it possible to create mui Dialog without jsx ,just using JavaScript , mui Dialog and react/reactDom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-dom, vaadin-flow

I wanted to create  mui Dialog  just using  mui-core , react , reactDom

without  jsx  syntax, wanted to  created dialog

Comment: Did you look at [`react.createElement`](https://react.dev/reference/react/createElement)?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`React.createElement`](https://react.dev/reference/react/createElement) instead of JSX.

Example:

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import {createElement, useState, Fragment} from 'react';

export default function Demo() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  return createElement(Fragment, {},
    createElement(Button, {onClick(){setOpen(true)}}, 'Open Dialog'),
    createElement(Dialog, {open, onClose(){setOpen(false)}}, 
    createElement(DialogTitle, {}, "Dialog Title"),
    createElement(DialogContent, {}, "Content"))
  );
}
```